# error con fragmenta y vertex shaders

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, webgl, glsl

hola buenos días espero alguien me pueda ayudar con el siguiente error que me sale consola y hace que rl navegador no muestre nada adjunto el codigo del archivo fragment.glsl. donde creo esta el error.

```
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
}
```

y del vertex.glsl

```
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    vUv = uv;

    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    gl_PointSize = 50.0 * ( 1.0 / - mvPosition.z );
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
}
```

en esta como lo utilizo en el JavaScript específicamente en la parte de addMesh. En cuanto al JavaScript puede tener error de sintaxis ya que al copiarlo a esta pregunta me pude haber equivocado

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import frag from './shaders/fragment.glsl';
import vert from './shaders/vertex.glsl';

export default class Sketch {
        constructor(){
                this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { 
antialias: true } );
                this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.getElementById('container').appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );
    

            this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
            this.camera.position.z = 1;   
            this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
            this.addMesh();
            this.time = 0;
            this.render();
    }
    addMesh(){
            this.geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 1, 1 );
            this.material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({ side: THREE.DoubleSide });
            this.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
                    fragmentShader:frag,
                    vertexShader:vert,
                    uniforms: {
                            progress: { type: "f", value: 0 }
                    },
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide
            }),
            this.mesh = new THREE.Points( this.geometry, this.material );
            this.scene.add( this.mesh );
    }


    render(){
            this.time++;
            this.mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
            this.mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;        
            this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );
            window.requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
    }
}
new Sketch():
```

y finalmento lo que me aparece en consola
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código debe ir como texto por favor. ;)

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código de las imágenes en tu pregunta como texto? Así podemos manipularlo más fácilmente y ayudarte :)

Comment: listo ya lo edite o igual no se si quieran que lo suba a github y  se los comparto. muchas gracias por su interes

Comment: https://github.com/aribezhennacre/test.git o aqui esta el repositorio en github

Answer (score 0):

El error es que se te olvido poner `;` al final de tu `vec4()` en el fragment shader. Simple y sensillo.

```glsl
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // Añade el ;
}
```